# Dynamic queries in MongoDB and Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I am working on a nodejs/express app with Mongodb on the backend. In one of my API calls, depending on the presence of a particular querystring parameter or the other I want to issue a query to Mongodb with either a $gt or a $lt.

In some cases we want to ask for everything less than the `tokenId` using $lt, but in other cases we want everything greater than the `tokenId` using $gt.  How do we do that without duplicating the queries?

Here's an example query:

```
collection.find({'film_id': {$in : genre}, '_id': {$lt: tokenId}}).sort({'_id': -1}).limit(25).toArray(function(error, films)
```

Is there a way to dynamically create the query without actually doing 2 different queries?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Build up your query object programmatically:

```
var query = {'film_id': {$in : genre}};
if (param) {
    query._id = {$lt: tokenId};
} else {
    query._id = {$gt: tokenId};
}
collection.find(query).sort({'_id': -1}).limit(25).toArray(function(error, films);
```

**Update**

Now that Node.js 4+ supports [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), you can create `query` in one step as:

```
var query = {
    film_id: {$in: genre},
    _id: {[param ? '$lt' : '$gt']: tokenId}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The Above code may not work. The above dynamic query will be resolved to following Ex. Token is an integer 35.

```
collection.find("_id":"{$gt: 35}")
          .sort({'_id': -1}).limit(25).toArray(function(error, films);
```

resulting in Error

**The correct syntax should be:**

```
collection.find("_id":{$gt: 35}).
```

The double "" quotes should not be there.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your post should be a comment or possibly an edit, not an answer. Or if you are still stuck, please post a new question.